# Quickly Adding a Value to a Numeric Property (in Org-Mode)

Tags: org-mode

Suppose we have

```
*** Sample Task
:PROPERTIES:
:Tally:    42
:END:
```

Is there a way to quickly add a number to `:Tally:` without having to compute the sum manually and changing the property by hand?

**EDIT:** I tried making an interactive region selecting function which replaces the first instance of :Tally: with the added value:

```
(defun tally-add (start end num)
  (interactive "r\nn Number:")
  (query-replace-regexp ":Tally:\ *\([0-9]+\)" "\,(format ":Tally: %d" (+ num \#1))" start end))
```

However, when running on a region I get "%d Symbol's value as a variable is void".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this instead:

```
(defun tally-add (n)
  (interactive "nN: ")
  (org-entry-put
   nil "TALLY"
   (format "%s" (+ n (string-to-number
                      (or (org-entry-get nil "TALLY") "0"))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `query-replace-regexp` to find the numbers and return a function applied to the number. Usual keybinding is <kbd>M-C-%</kbd>.

For the query, find lines with the property and match the number parte:

```
:Tally:\ *\([0-9]+\)
```

For the replacement, call an elisp form that reproduces the property line (in this case, adding 3 to the number found):

```
\,(format ":Tally: %d" (+ 3 \#1))
```

The `\#1` tag [refers to](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html) the first match group interpreted as a number.

Comment: I tried making a function from this answer above but am getting an error. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: What is the error? I re-tested it again on the sample you provided.